# Can the Netflix app be loaded on an Acer Iconia A500 without rooting?

Tags: 3.2-honeycomb, acer-iconia-a500, netflix

Acer recently released an official upgrade to 3.2 for the Iconia A500 tablet, but the Netflix app is still not visible in the market.  Is it possible to get the Netflix app on this tablet without rooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hacked apk from here works: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=18058380&postcount=147